# Railo session storage using DynamoDB on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, railo, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are hosting Tomcat / Railo on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and it appears that database session storage is the best option for coping with the multiple servers that a request may be passed between as a consequence of load-balancing.

Amazon have some [dedicated modules for doing this in PHP](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/04/scalable-session-handling-in-php-using-amazon-dynamodb.html), and I would like to know if anything similar exists for Railo?

Incidentally, I am aware that enabling "sticky sessions" is another option, but it seems to me that sessions will be lost if machines are taken off-line (i.e. spun-down by the load balancer), which would be annoying for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a DynamoDB cache provider, however Railo can store sessions in any cache or datasource that it currently supports (see [the docs](http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/3-3%3aSession_storage)) if you enable it for storage and then specify it in the Application.cfc

In the railo web admin create a datasource to use for storing sessions, half way down the page tick "Storage:  Allow to use this datasource as client/session storage."

In you Application.cfc add the following

```
this.sessionStorage = "my_sessions_dsn";
this.sessionCluster = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Chris; I'll use this as the starting point.